# Count daily signups over n days with Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I need to get the number of signups each day to a rails application over a period of days, and stick them in an array. I currently have a working solution, but I'm sure there's a much better way to do this than having to query the database n times.

My current solution:

```
signups = []

30.times.do |i|
  day = Time.current - (29.days - i.days)
  todays_signups = User.where(time_joined: day.beginning_of_day..day.end_of_day).count
  signups << todays_signups
end
```

`User.time_joined` is a `DATETIME` column.

I'm sure there's a much better way to do this than hitting the database 30 times, and I'd like to avoid using raw SQL queries if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it just via SQL-query:

```
User.where(time_joined: your_interval).group("DATE(time_joined)").count
```

Comment: Don't just post an tiny answer quickly and then make a bunch of edits after that. Instead, take your time to write a good answer

Comment: You first posted the following answer: "User.group("DATE(time_joined)").count". And from there you kept doing edits until you came up with an ok answer.

Comment: @karlingen, just see edits, and voting on answer. If you copy my answer almost full, it is your problems, man. Be impartial to answers, it is a good practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ilya, this is exactly what I needed. Unsure why you were downvoted, but I'll most likely accept this answer.

Comment: @JackBracken, it is just hater.